# How to manipulate a given String to get 2 different string using regex?

Tags: java, regex, string

I need to do to a String manipulation. Initially I will be getting an image path as one of the below:

```
image = images/registration/student.gif
image = images/registration/student_selected.gif
image = images/registration/student_highlighted.gif
```

and I need to manipulate the string image path to get 2 different image paths.

One is to get the path as:

```
image1 = images/registration/student.gif
```

for that I used the function below:

```
private String getImage1(final String image) {
    String image1 = image;
    image1 = image.replace("_highlight", "");
    image1 = image.replace("_selected", "");
    return image1;
}
```

the second image path I need is to get the path:

```
image2 = image = images/registration/student_selected.gif
```

the function I used to get the `image2` output was:

```
private String getImage2(final String image) {
    String image2 = image;
    boolean hasUndersore = image2.matches("_");
    if (hasUndersore) {
        image2 = image2.replace("highlight", "selected");
    } else {
        String[] words = image2.split("\\.");
        image2 = words[0].concat("_selected.") + words[1];
    }
    return image2;
}
```

But the above methods didn't give me the expected result. Can anyone help me with it? 
Thanks a lot!

Comment: can you give some unexpected results.

Comment: it seems getImage1 will only replace `_selected` since you overwrite the image1 variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could use indexOf(...) instead of match(). match will check the whole string against the regex.

```
for (final String image : new String[] { "images/registration/student.gif", "images/registration/student_highlight.gif",
                "images/registration/student_selected.gif" }) {

            String image2 = image;
            final boolean hasUndersore = image2.indexOf("_") > 0;
            if (hasUndersore) {
                image2 = image2.replaceAll("_highlight(\\.[^\\.]+)$", "_selected$1");
            } else {
                final String[] words = image2.split("\\.");
                image2 = words[0].concat("_selected.") + words[1];
            }
            System.out.println(image2);
        }
```

this will give you expected output.

btw, i changed replaceAll(..) regex, since the image filename could have string "highlight" as well. e.g. `stuhighlight_highlight.jpg`

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly, you need below outputs from respective functions

```
"images/registration/student.gif"-> getImage1(String) 
"images/registration/student_selected.gif" -> getImage2(String)
```

Assuming above output, there are few mistakes in the both functions
getImage1()->

- In the second replace you need to use image1 variable which is output of first replace.
- You need to replace "_highlighted" and not "_highlight"

getImage2()->

- If you need to search for '_' then use indexOf function.
- You need to replace 'highlighted' not 'highlight'

I have modified the functions as below which gives required output

```
private static String getImage1(final String image) {
    return image.replace("_highlighted", "").replace("_selected", "");
}
private static String getImage2(final String image) {
    if (image.indexOf("_")!=-1) {
        return image.replace("highlighted", "selected");
    } else {
        return image.replace(".", "_selected.");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, getImage1() is probably not doing what you want it to do. You are assigning a value to the variable image1 3 times. Obviously the last assigned value gets returned.

Second, `image2.matches("_")` will *not* tell you if image2 contains an underscore (which I think is what you're trying to do here).

I suggest to do some more testing/debugging yourself first.

Answer (score 0):

1.

```
private String getImage1(final String image) {
  return image.replaceAll("_(highlighted|selected)", "");
}
```

2.

```
private String getImage2(final String image) {
  return image.replaceAll(getImage1(image).replaceAll("(?=.gif)", "_selected");
}
```